# Self Referencing Class Definition in python

Tags: python

is there any way to reference a class name from within the class declaration? an example follows:

```
class Plan(SiloBase):
    cost = DataField(int)
    start = DataField(System.DateTime)
    name = DataField(str)
    items = DataCollection(int)
    subPlan = ReferenceField(Plan)
```

i've got a metaclass that reads this information and does some setup, and the base class implements some common saving stuff. i would love to be able to create recursive definitions like this, but so far in my experimentation i have been unable to get the effect i desire, usually running into a "Plan is not defined" error. I understand what is happening, the name of the class isn't in scope inside the class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> i've got a metaclass that reads this information and does some setup

Most frameworks that use metaclasses provide a way to resolve this.  For instance, [Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

```
subplan = ForeignKey('self')
```

[Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#SelfReferenceProperty):

```
subplan = SelfReferenceProperty()
```

The problem with solutions like tacking an additional property on later or using `__new__` is that most ORM metaclasses expect the class properties to exist at the time when the class is created.

Comment: Great that you mentioned Google App Engine as well! +1

Comment: In Google App Engine - DB has this, but NDB does not. To see how to do this in NDB look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531936/selfreferenceproperty-question

Answer (score 25):

**Try this:**

```
class Plan(SiloBase):
    cost = DataField(int)
    start = DataField(System.DateTime)
    name = DataField(str)
    items = DataCollection(int)

Plan.subPlan = ReferenceField(Plan)
```

**OR use `__new__` like this:**

```
class Plan(SiloBase):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.cost = DataField(int)
        cls.start = DataField(System.DateTime)
        cls.name = DataField(str)
        cls.items = DataCollection(int)
        cls.subPlan = ReferenceField(cls)
        return object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: awesome, this does exactly what i want it to, and its not a humongous hack. still trying to wrap my head around this whole dynamic thing, haha

Answer (score 2):

> I understand what is happening, the
>   name of the class isn't in scope
>   inside the class.

Not exactly. The name of the class **is not yet defined** when defining it's contents (e.g. scope).

Answer (score 1):

Sine Python 3.7 and [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) there's a way to do that.

Add the import

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

and the following code will work

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import List

class Refer(object):
    def __init__(self, x: Plan):
        self.x: Plan = x

class Plan(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    subPlan: Refer(Plan())
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that. Think about what would happen if you did this:

```
 OtherPlan = Plan
 other_plan = OtherPlan()
```

At instantiation of `other_plan`, what is the name of the class?

Anyway, this sort of thing is best done in the `__new__` method, which takes a `cls` parameter referring to the class.