# type control decorator python on method

Tags: python

I'm trying to a write type control decorator of function which also works on method inside class.
So I have to take account of self parameter appearing in method.
But i don't know how to detect this case.

Here is the code of my decorator:

```
def typedef_control(*args, **kwargs):
    """Decorator with parameters"""
    def decorator(func):
        """Decorator return changed function"""
        def func_changed(*args_, **kwargs_):
            if(len(args) != len(args_)):
                    raise IOError("Nombre d'argument de la fonction différent de celui du décorateur")    
            for i, arg_ in enumerate(args_):
                if args[i] is not type(arg_):
                    raise TypeError("Argument {0} n'est pas de type {1}".format(i, args[i]))
            for key in kwargs_:
                if key not in kwargs:
                    raise TypeError("Argument {0} sans type".format(repr(key)))
                if kwargs[key] is not type(kwargs_[key]):
                    raise TypeError("Argument {0} n'est pas de type {1}".format(repr(key), kwargs[key]))
            return func(*args_, **kwargs_)
        return func_changed
    return decorator
```

Here an example:

```
class MyClass:
@typedef_control(int)
def __init__(self, param_int)
    pass
```

As expected, it will enter in the first if statement if(len(args) != len(args_)).

So i have to add a condition on args_[0]. I guess self is the object created in **new** method by inheriting.
Now i don't know what to do with that.

If you have any idea I would be pleased to hear from you.

Comment: That's a very unpythonic thing you're trying to do.

Comment: I guess the decorator itself is unpythonic because it goes against dynamic typing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the same decorator (with arguments) with functions and methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288498/using-the-same-decorator-with-arguments-with-functions-and-methods)

Comment: Your problem is that if you do `x = MyClass(3)`, `__init__` is being called with two arguments, the first of type `MyClass` and the second of type `int`.  However, referencing the type of the class while you're defining it is tricky.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020279/self-referencing-class-definition-in-python).