# Python recursive class reference - how to make a tree

Tags: python, django, django-models

What's wrong with this?

```
class Cat():
    parent = Cat()
```

> NameError: name 'Cat' is not defined

All I wanted to do was to create a class that could be nested to create a tree of category objects.  What's the standard way of doing this?

I will eventually be putting this in Django as a Model and syncing with SQLite3. I am a Python newbie.  Sorry...

Comment: How exactly do you plan to do this without recursing infinitely, since each `Cat`'s parent is a brand new `Cat`?

Comment: Thanks all for your answers.  It is a duplicate and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1020431/1369798

Comment: The short answer is: class Cat(self): parent = ForeignKey('self')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to create a `Cat` object before the definition of the Cat class is completed.

This version is syntactically legal, but will create an infinite list of cats :

```
class Cat():
    def __init__(self):
         self.parent = Cat()
```

What you probably want is something like this:

```
class Cat():
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         self.parent = parent
```

Comment: This will recurse infinitely, won't it?

Comment: Yes. The first version will, but the second version is probably what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent = parent

Cat(Cat("dog"))
```

maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the problems of infinite recursion, it's a mistake to model something as a plain class and then later think about how you would convert it into a Django model. This is because of the [object-relational impedence mismatch](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_impedance_mismatch): Django models are meant to be stored in the database, and relational dbs never match up perfectly with oop concepts.

Luckily, there exists a very good algorithm for spring hierarchical data, which is MPTT, and a good Django implementation of that, [django-mptt](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/).